# why does a file written using writfFileSync method is corrupted for a video file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs

I am uploading a video file to my s3 bucket using a presigned URL using the following code

```
function postsignedURL(req) {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       const params = {
          Bucket: 'bucket1',
          Expires: 60 * 60, // in seconds,
          Fields: {
             key: req,
             'Content-Type': 'video/'
          },
         Conditions: [
            ['content-length-range', 300, 4000e+7],
            { 'Content-Type': 'video/' },
            ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "video/"]

        ]
    }
    s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err)
        } else {
            resolve(data);
        }
    })
})

}
```

I am able to upload the file correctly and I can even download it using the following code in

```
 const video = await readObjectSignedUrl(key)
 console.log(video, " video ");
```

This one returns a presigned url. I can download the video using fetch method below

```
 const objectResult = await fetchS3Object(video);
 const bufferType = Buffer.from(objectResult);
 const fileTypeResult = await fileType.fromBuffer(bufferTy[e);
 console.log(fileTypeResult )
```

The result of fileTypeResult is the following which is correct

```
{ ext: 'mov', mime: 'video/quicktime' }
```

The code for the fetchS3Object is the following

```
async function fetchS3Object(key) {
   console.log(key," KEY ")
   const result = await fetch(key, {
       method: 'GET',
       mode: "cors",
       headers: {
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
       }
   })
   const response = await result.text()
   return response
}
```

When i print the objectResult variable it is some gibberish. 
I am trying to write the objectResult to file using writeFileSync method.

```
fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/file', objectResult);
```

The file is written correctly in the specified location, but the video file is corrupted. When I try to play it, it is not working.

Is there is a reason why the written file is corrupted

Comment: I don't know what type of response you're trying to use `fetch()` on, but you probably need to read the body with `res.text()`, `res.json()` or something like that.  Look at the doc for `fetch()` to see how you get the body contents.  `fetch()` all by itself just gets a response object with headers and the like and a stream ready to ready the response from.  You then need an additional step to read and parse the body from the incoming stream.

Comment: I am sorry i havent included the correct code. I have edited the question. Indeed I did apply .text() at the end of fetchS3Object function

Comment: Can't read your `fetchS3Object()` code very well because of the lack of indentation.

Comment: I have indented it please check

Comment: What is the fetched content supposed to be?  What is the `content-type` you get back from the response?  Is it supposed to be text/plain?  If it's actually a video, then it might be MIME encoded.

Comment: I have added extra pieces to my question. If I change the objectResult variable to buffer and get fileType. The extension is .MOV and mimeType is 'video/quicktime'

Comment: The Node.js default encoding is utf8 which is not the right way for getting file as binary. Try to set the encoding to `null`

Comment: you mean when using writefilesync

Comment: @Ahmed when getting response. I never used s3 but I think it is probably on your fetch method options

Comment: @AmadouBeye you are correct the encoding of binary is return as utf-8 however original file has an encoding of windows-1252. Is there is a way to pass encoding parameter to fetch method because it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Managed to solve the problem. Here is the issue. The problem arise from the fact that the original uploaded file which is a video had an encoding of

```
windows-1252,
```

However the fetch method return a binary which is encoded with

```
UTF-8.
```

As a result when you try to use writeFileSync the output is a corrupted file.
To solve this problem this what has to be done. The fetchS3Object function has to be changed to the following

```
async function fetchS3Object(key) {
   console.log(key," KEY ")
   const result = await fetch(key, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      }
   })
   const response = await result.arrayBuffer();
   return response
}
```

then

```
 const objectResult = await fetchS3Object(video);
 const bufferType = Buffer.from(objectResult);
 fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/file', bufferType);
```